# Import PDF in Inkscape without per character spacing

Tags: pdf, inkscape, svg

I have a PDF form I imported into Inkscape.  It did a pretty great job of created an SVG from it, however it appears to have given per character x coordinates to each tspan in every text block.  I'm not sure, but I think this is making the FOP render that our software does ridiculously slow (running it through other renderers like IBEX it seems fine).

I'd like to import it but have it not do per character positions.  I can't seem to find any sort of PDF importing options at all.  Does such a thing exist?  Or is there perhaps some other, better freeware application I could use to generate the SVG from the PDF then use Inkscape to do adjustments from there?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never figured out how to do what my question was asking, but the slowness was caused due to what I mention in this question over at SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926038/why-does-fop-take-so-long-to-send-this-document-to-the-printer